# Lanzar ventana cuando acaba el proceso en ffmpeg. PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

En Python, PyQt y ffmpeg: Necesito aprender cómo hacer aparecer una ventana con el típico mensaje: "El proceso ha finalizado" Esa ventana tiene que aparecer cuando el proceso de ffmpeg acabe. Ffmpeg lo lanzo con subprocess.
No consigo saber como ejecutar "algo" cuando un proceso acaba.
Este es mi código (por ahora):

```
import sys
   from PyQt4.QtCore import *
   from PyQt4.QtGui import *
   import subprocess



   fileinput = ''

   def window():
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      win = QDialog()
      b1 = QPushButton(win)
      b1.setText("Select file")
      b1.move(50,20)
      b1.clicked.connect(b1_clicked)

      b2 = QPushButton(win)
      b2.setText("Output file")
      b2.move(50,50)
      b2.clicked.connect(b2_clicked)

      b3 = QPushButton(win)
      b3.setText("Encode!")
      b3.move(50,80)
      b3.clicked.connect(b3_clicked)

      win.setGeometry(100,100,200,200)
      win.setWindowTitle("Encoder")
      win.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())

   def b1_clicked():
      global fileinput
      fileinput = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Selecciona archivo a convertir", "/home/salva", "video files (*.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.mov *.mpg);; All files (*)")
      print (fileinput)


   def b2_clicked():
      filesaved = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Archivo de salida", "/home/salva", "video files (*.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.mov *.mpg);; All files (*)")
      print (filesaved)


   def b3_clicked():
       subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', fileinput, filesaved])


   if __name__ == '__main__':
      window()
```

**EDITO:**

Para entender mejor mi problema, construyo un código muy simple e intento que salga ventana emergente pero no funciona:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


a = 20
if a == 20:
    print (a)
    QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Información", "Se ha procesado {0}".format(a),QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
```

El error que me da es este:

> QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Información", "Se ha procesado
>   {0}".format(a),QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok) NameError: name 'QtGui' is not
>   defined

**EDITO II:**

Me he trabajado un código más sencillo y a medida de lo que estoy haciendo para averiguar cómo lanzar una ventana cuando el botón 3 acabe su proceso. Lo he intentado pero no me funciona. Tengo una ventana principal: **window** y otra que es la que tiene que aparecer cuando el botón 3 acabe su proceso: **winok**
Necesito que se cierre la ventana window y aparezca la ventana winok al acabar el proceso el botón 3. También saber cómo verificar el valor de retorno del boton 3 (que será lo que haga ffmpeg en un futuro) y mostrar mensaje de error o de éxito.
Esto es lo que tengo por ahora orientado a solucionar lo de la ventana:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


def window():

   win = QDialog()

   b1 = QPushButton(win)
   b1.setText("Select file")
   b1.move(50,20)
   b1.clicked.connect(b1_clicked)

   b2 = QPushButton(win)
   b2.setText("Output file")
   b2.move(50,50)
   b2.clicked.connect(b2_clicked)

   b3 = QPushButton(win)
   b3.setText("Encode!")
   b3.move(50,80)
   b3.clicked.connect(b3_clicked)

   win.setGeometry(100,100,200,200)
   win.setWindowTitle("Encoder")
   win.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

def b1_clicked():
    print('boton 1 pulsado')


def b2_clicked():
    print('boton 2 pulsado')


def b3_clicked():
   print ('boton 3 pulsado')
   winok()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window()


def winok():

    win = QDialog()

    b10 = QPushButton(win)
    b10.setText("Do another job?")
    b10.move(50,20)
    b10.clicked.connect(b10_clicked)

    b11 = QPushButton(win)
    b11.setText("Exit")
    b11.move(50,50)
    b11.clicked.connect(b11_clicked)

    win.setGeometry(100,100,300,100)
    win.setWindowTitle("Work completed. Oh Yeah!")
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def b10_clicked():
    print ('Volviendo a codificar...')


def b11_clicked():
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo que se me ocurre es usar [QMessageBox](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html):

```
def b3_clicked():
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', fileinput, filesaved])
    QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Información", "Se ha procesado {0}".format(fileinput),QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
```

Lo correcto en realidad sería verificar el valor de retorno del ffmpeg y mostrar mensaje de error o de éxito, pero el ejemplo que te paso es fácilmente adaptable

Comment: Gracias @Patricio, lo he probado y no me funciona. Me rertorna este error: NameError: name 'QtGui' is not defined
soy bastante nuevo en esto y de hecho no entiendo la parte final de tu propuesta: `{0}".format(fileinput),QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)`

Comment: Es por que hay importar los el objeto QtGui. Agrega al comienzo del script  `from PyQt4.QtGui import *`

Comment: Lo tengo importado. Eso es lo curioso No se por qué pasa ?¿?

Comment: He editado la pregunta con un código más simple para intentar entender como lo soluciono. No lo consigo.